How to select one row from several tables with unique user_ids?
I have some list of unique user_ids which located in several different tables and I want to pull the user out with only one SELECT statement (at least in code).
I have these ORM models in my models.py:
class AbstractAccount(DeclarativeBase):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, unique=True, doc='Unique account id')
    full_name = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    phone = Column(TEXT, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        columns = {column.name: getattr(self, column.name) for column in self.__table__.columns}
        return f'<{self.__tablename__}: {", ".join(map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}={x[1]}", columns.items()))}>'


class UserAccount(AbstractAccount):
    __tablename__ = 'user_account'

class DoctorAccount(AbstractAccount):
    __tablename__ = 'doctor_account'
    
    specialty_id = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey('specialty.id'))

Now in routers.py I want to pull out the user from one of all tables inherited from AbstractAccount:
@api_router.get(
    "/get_user",
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
)
async def check(
    user_id: int,
    session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session),
):
    '''
    Some docstring
    '''
    account_query = select(AbstractAccount).filter(AbstractAccount.id == user_id)
    account = await session.scalar(account_query)
    if account:
        return account
    return -1

When I try to execute this query, I get the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got \<class 'pharmacy.models.account.AbstractAccount\>.
Same problem I experience with my AbstractItem model (I have items in different tables but with unique ids):
class AbstractItem(DeclarativeBase):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, unique=True, doc='Unique item id')
    name = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    amount = Column(INTEGER, nullable=False)
    price = Column(NUMERIC(8, 2), nullable=False)
    dosage_form = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    manufacturer = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    barcode = Column(TEXT, nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        columns = {column.name: getattr(self, column.name) for column in self.__table__.columns}
        return f'<{self.__tablename__}: {", ".join(map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}={x[1]}", columns.items()))}>'


class CommonItem(AbstractItem):
    __tablename__ = 'common_item'

class ReceiptItem(AbstractItem):
    __tablename__ = 'receipt_item'

I've been seeing some examples with polymorphic_indentity, but I still didn't manage to implement this in my FastAPI app. The reason I want to implement exactly with abstract model is probability of scaling the amount of types of users.

Generally in an RDBMS this shouldn't be different tables, but have a field that indicates its type, and a secondary table for each type and their custom fields; that will make everything far easier to handle in the future, avoiding to have different relationship joins and foreign keys for each type you're linking between tables.
